# Optimize an existing for-loop over three arrays

Tags: python, arrays, performance, for-loop, optimization

I have three lists/arrays: one is a list of boolean values, the other two are arrays with certain values.
My goal is to loop through the boolean list and if the value is true take the j-th value of the first array and safe it in the solution array, and if the value is false take the j-th value of the second array and safe it into the solution array.

This is my solution right now:

```
j = 0
for comp, i in zip(boolean_list,range(len(boolean_list))):
   if comp == False: 
      solutio_array[i] = first_array[j]
   else:
      solutio_array[i] = second_array[j]
   j += 1
```

This looks way too complicated and Fortran-Style for Python. So my question is, how can I solve this problem more efficiently in Python?

Thank you for your help! I want to improve my Python skills and this kind of coding seems way too rookie.

Comment: Does it have to be in pure python or can you use numpy?

Comment: solutio_array[i] = first_array if comp else second_array[i] # to make it more compact :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These things can be improved:

1. No need to do `range(len(boolean_list))` and zip it with the results. That is what `enumerate` is for.
2. No need for `j`, because `i==j` always.
3. Don't compare `x == True` or `x == False` - that is bad practice. Just do `if x`

Also, you had an error - your code takes from first array if `comp` is `False`, instead of from the second array.

All together, I would do this:

```
for i, comp in enumerate(boolean_list):
    if comp:
        solutio_array[i] = first_array[i]
    else:
        solutio_array[i] = second_array[i]
```

Or, *maybe* this:

```
for i, comp in enumerate(boolean_list):
    source_array = first_array if comp else second_array
    solutio_array[i] = source_array[i]
```

On the other hand, you could avoid using `i` at all, if you are creating a new `solutio_array`:

```
solutio_array = [first if comp else second
                 for first, second, comp
                 in zip(first_array, second_array, boolean_list)]
```

Comment: nice explanation :)

Comment: @zvone: What should I do if the arrays (first and second) have different sizes? I oversaw this aspect in your first reply. this was the reason why I included the variable  - j -. The three solutions of yours don't apply to different sized arrays.
cheers!

Comment: @zvone: your first solution would work easily with another variable (j). For instance:
j = 0
for i, comp in enumerate(boolean_list):
    if comp:
        solutio_array[i] = first_array[i]
    else:
        solutio_array[i] = second_array[j]
        j += 1

however this doen't seem like a efficient solution. Is there a way without including j?

Comment: @EugenBoos What would you want to happen in that case? If the arrays have different sizes, than my solution uses the smallest length of the three arrays. Your solution with `j` works uses the size of `boolean_list` which may cause an exception if e.g. the boolean value is true, but first array is shorter. An alternative is to use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) instead of `zip`, but in the end it is up to you to define which behaviour you want.